# Scalar Valued Function calling from different DB

Tags: sql-server, function

I have scalar-valued function in DB1;

**Function Using**: `Udf_NumberToInfo(Number)`
**Return**: Info of desired number

I have table in DB1;

**Column1**: Number
**Column2**: Info

I have numbers in DB2 and want query them in DB2 and groupby them. Let me explain with sample query;

```
USE DB2
select DB1..dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number) as INFO,COUNT(*) as count from NumberTable (nolock)
where Numbers like '5%'
group by DB1..dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number)
```

Query return:

```
Remote function reference 'DB1..dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo' is not allowed, and the column name 'DB1' could not be found or is ambiguous.
```

How can I use remote scalar valued function in DB1?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just create the Udf_NumberToInfo scalar function in DB2?

Comment: Are you aware of all the challenges throwing NOLOCK into a query brings? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate rows? If so, you need to at least use the proper syntax and use the WITH keyword. Omitting it has been deprecated and you will have to use it in the future.

Comment: I would suggest that dropping the scalar function would be the best way to go. Scalar functions are notoriously bad for performance and the worst performing method of their usage is in the list of columns. You would be better off with an inline table valued function. That means a single select, not multiple statements. The latter is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

It should work because you use db1..dbo it should be db1.dbo
I tested it in my local machine.
check this out

```
USE DB2
select DB1.dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number) as INFO,COUNT(*) as count from 
NumberTable (nolock)
where Numbers like '5%'
group by DB1.dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number)
```

Comment: `group by DB1..dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number)` ??

Comment: no it will be group by DB1.dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo(Number)

Comment: my question is why `..`(2 dots)??

Comment: .. (2 dots) allow you to access default schema, but in your script you already specified schema name which is dbo so it will be dbname.schemaname.objectname or dbname..objectname (for default schema)

Answer (score 1):

The double-dot notation in SQL Server means: use the **current user's** default schema (or default database).

Using `DBName..myFunction` means: The `myFunction` function in the **user's default schema** in `DBName` database. By default, the default schema is dbo, but it could be altered.

Lets assume that the userA has the `cust` schema as it's default schema and userB has the `dbo` schema as default. In this case when userA executes the `DBName..myFunction` function it will point to the `DBName.cust.myFunction`, but when userB executes it, it will point to `DBName.dbo.myFunction`

In your case `DB1..dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo` means: Use the Udf_NuberToInfo function on the linked server named DB1 in the users's default database and in schema named dbo.

Assuming that DB1 and DB2 is hosted on the same server, you should use `DB1.dbo.Udf_NumberToInfo`.

For more info about identifiers  please read the following article on MSDN: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx